# How to set to use the latest version of a package in pubspec.yaml?

Tags: dart

How to set to use the latest version of a package in pubspec.yaml for Dart projects?

Can I do something like:

```
dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: latest
  build_web_compilers: latest
```

in pubspec.yaml

Comment: I tried to do similar, but for Git `url` and `ref`. I don't believe it is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [version constraints documentation](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#version-constraints) for how package version constraints can be specified.

There is no direct way to use the "latest" version of a package, but that is not a good idea since a later version of a package might not be backward compatible.

You instead can do:

```
some_package: ">= 1.2.3 < 2.0.0"
```

since packages should use [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/spec/v2.0.0-rc.1.html) and change the major version number to indicate backward-incompatible changes.

You also can use:

```
some_package: "^1.2.3"
```

to indicate package versions expected to be compatible with 1.2.3 (but this is based on semantic versioning conventions and is equivalent to `">= 1.2.3 < 2.0.0"`.

Finally, if you *really* don't care about package versions at all, you could specify an unrealistically high maximum version:

```
some_package: ">= 1.2.3 < 9999999.0.0"
```

or disable version constraints entirely:

```
some_package: any
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this is not what I want. I just want the latest version regardless whether it's a good idea or not.

Comment: @sgon00 As I said, there is no way to do exactly what you want, so I proposed some ways of achieving a similar effect. (And I've now added another one.)

Comment: Hi, I have marked your question as the answer. But I just tried your updated way and put `build_web_compilers: ">= 1.6.0 < 10.0.0"` to pubspec.yaml, but it doesn't work. It still remains 2.0.0. But if I change it to `build_web_compilers: ^2.1.2`, it does update to 2.1.2. Thus the updated solution does not really work to keep the package always up-to-date.

Comment: @sgon00 Did you run `pub upgrade`?  A new version won't be downloaded automatically if what's cached already satisfies the version constraints.